# Conditional for a future plan conditioned by your available time

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

Which one of these is correct, to speak about a future plan and time?

> - I will come to the party if I have time
> - I would come to the party if I had time
> - I will come to the party if I would have time

Also I'm open to other suggestions :)

Comment: Another suggestion is "I come to the party if I have time".

Comment: @Carlo_R Simple present would be used in the main clause **only** if the party is a recurrent event and you are speaking about your usual practice - "I come to the regular Friday-afternoon office blowout whenever I have the time."

Comment: @Carlo_R. What Stoney said--yours is almost right, you're just one word off. Try "I *will* come..." :)

Comment: @WendiKidd yes! but that one word is really important and the outcome will be the first choice above :)

Comment: @Wendi, but elsewhere, perhaps on EL&U, I'm sure of having read that "I come to the party ... blah, blah, blah" is not *wrong*, but only *informal*. However, now, I'm not able to find the place where I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence is a promise: you tell your hearer that if you have the time you will definitely come.

Your second sentence is a regret: the past-tense forms indicate that the condition is a "counterfactual", a condition contrary to fact, so you cannot come - but if you could you would.

Your third sentence is not idiomatic English. *Will* and *would* are never used in a condition (*IF*) clause in a futurive sense, but only in a *volitional* sense - that is, when they mean *be willing*.

> If you will do this = "If you are willing to do this" or "If you consent to do this".
>   If you would do this = "If you were willing to do this" or "If you consented to do this".